# Does 'Deploy with Active Jobs' work for managed packages?

Tags: managed-package, batch, deployment, scheduled-apex, metadata

So there's this new feature: ['Deploy with Active Jobs'](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_deploy_with_jobs.htm)

It lets you deploy batches and schedules even if they're running.

[image: deployment-options]

This is great for changesets. Does it work with **managed packages**?

Comment: It has worked for me, but since I was not specifically paying attention for this exact scenario when I did it I am not posting an answer just yet.....